# How to treat delocalized pi bonds in DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, atoms-in-molecules

For a structure such benzene, the pi bonds between the carbon atoms are said to be de-localized. Therefore the electrons are expected to be exchanged in between individual C-C bonds.

When dealing with DFT calculations of such a structure, should there be any additional considerations to ensure the accuracy of the results?

Comment: Try Charge density difference or Electron localization function to identify the spatial distribution of charge and electron.

Comment: @pranavkumar would it be possible to suggest a reference in this regard?

Comment: Several article you can find using ELF to define character of bond, here is one of them which can be useful https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=1903

Comment: @pranavkumar thanks. This is helpful as a starter.

Comment: I don't think any other considerations are required in most cases. The usual quantum chemistry codes that work with Hartree-Fock or DFT wavefunctions usually handle delocalized pi-bonds accurately. On the other hand, running a valence bond type calculation would require some careful tuning of the settings. This is because the usual Hartree-Fock type calculations consider all orbitals are delocalized (in the sense that they can have contributions from all atomic orbitals), and does not attempt to localize them.

Comment: @SRMaiti thanks

Comment: @SRMaiti Your comment could likely be converted to a reasonable answer.

Comment: @SRMaiti do you think you might have time some day to follow-through with the suggestion by Tyberius? I think it would be nice to clear this from the unanswered queue if possible!

Comment: @NikeDattani Hmm, I don't know how to answer the second part though. Maybe some kind of NBO or localization?

Comment: @SRMaiti No worries, I was just going based off of the comment by Tyberius where it suggests that your comment might be sufficient. There's a reason why we have a "one question per post policy" here, because otherwise if people only know how to answer one or the other, then questions remain in the unanswered queue forever, which gives us less ability to focus on other questions in the unanswered queue. I've commented out the second question and PBH can ask that one separately if desired! If you think you can answer the first question, go for it!

Comment: @SRMaiti sorry for the inclusion of a second part in the question. However your comment was more than helpful to answer most of the doubts which I had!!

Comment: @SRMaiti Since, your comment was "more than helpful to answer" most of OP's doubts, would you consider to write an answer? PBH, maybe you could write a self-answer if SRMaiti doesn't want to write one? If most of the doubts have been answered, then it seems that compiling some of the information from the comments into an answer, would be highly valuable for future visitors to the site! I've added this question to the list of "almost answered questions" here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/5

Comment: @NikeDattani, the comment by SRMaiti is actually the answer to the question. Yes it can be improved by the addition of references etc, but that is something which needs to be done by someone with experience in the field. I refrained from answering the question because of these two reasons. So if someone else is willing to copy paste the comment as an answer, I'd be wiling and happy to edit and improve it as I keep reading on the matter.

Comment: Let's give some time for SRMaiti to write an answer, and if you believe someone with more experience in the field is required for additional references, those can always be added in a second answer :)

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry, was busy with exams and didn't get the time to check for comments. Feel free to delete my previous comments if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common form of the self-consistent field (SCF) calculations, which are used in DFT and Hartree-Fock, assumes that each molecular orbital is a linear combination of all the atomic orbitals (aka basis function), and that the molecular orbitals are orthogonal to each other.
$$\psi^\mathrm{MO}_\mathrm{i} = \sum_\mathrm{p} c_\mathrm{pi} \chi^\mathrm{AO}_\mathrm{p}$$

So you start with $n$ atomic orbitals, and by taking linear combinations, you get $n$ orthogonal MO's. These molecular orbitals are called canonical orbitals. (Assuming there is no linear dependency in the AO basis set)

As the SCF procedure assumes from the start that each MO can have contributions from all of the AO's, the concept of delocalization is built into the procedure by default.

Therefore, when you do a DFT calculation on a molecule like benzene, no other considerations are required. If there is any delocalization, it will be treated by the method.

For example, have a look at the HOMO-1 orbital of butadiene (which is supposed to the lowest $\pi$-orbital, which all of the 2p-orbitals of carbon overlapping constructively) from a B3LYP/6-31+G(2d,p) calculation:

[image: butadiene lowest pi orbital]

It is quite clear that the delocalization is accounted for.

---

As an aside, I want to add that even if you start with localized orbitals, the canonical wavefunction can be obtained by taking linear combination of the various different ways you can localize the orbitals. This is something I learnt in my quantum chemistry lectures, and the math works out, but it is difficult to have an intuitive sense of why this works. So for example you can write the structure of benzene in two Kekule forms, and it turns out that the canonical wavefunction of benzene is simply a linear combination of both - benzene exists as a superposition of the Kekule-type localized wavefunctions.

There can only be one set of canonical MO's that satisfy the orthonormality condition, but there can be multiple way to localize the MO's. There are actually some exotic quantum chemistry methods (such as ALMO), which actually start with localized wavefunctions (determined for specified fragments of the system), and then builds up the total wavefunction from those fragmented localized MO's. This works quite efficiently for large systems such as water clusters, because there is no delocalization, so electron-electron interaction only happens locally.

Comment: `+1` and welcome to the 5000 points club!

Comment: "So you start with n atomic orbitals, and by taking linear combinations, you get n orthogonal MO's." Only if the basis set has no linear dependencies, which is the case only in very small (minimal) basis sets.

Comment: @SusiLehtola I thought QM softwares usually remove linear dependencies before SCF starts? I wasn't thinking about linear dependency when writing the answer, but I guess you are right.

Comment: @SRMaiti exactly, which is why the number of MOs is generally smaller than the number of AOs.